# How to remove the leading zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

Table1

```
ID column1 column2  (datatype is nvarchar)

001 08.50 17.50
002 17.20 16.52
003 09.50 01.00
....
```

I want to remove the zero's from the table1 like 8.5 17.5....

Expected Ouput

```
ID column1 column2 

001 8.5 17.5
002 17.2 16.52
003 9.5 1
....
```

How to do this.

Need Sql Query Help

Comment: What is the data type of that field?

Comment: datatype is nvarchar(20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
select cast (017.50 as float)
```

you should use float because if you use numeric, it requires a scale and if the scale is bigger than the number's scale, it wont remove the end zeros. For example:

```
select cast (017.50 as numeric(10,2)) = 17.50
```

if you do `10,1` it would round numbers like 16.52, so float is the best option

Answer (score 3):

Redesign the database so the type of the columns is appropriate for the data being contained in them.

Answer (score 1):

cast your column to number when performing the select

Comment: "number" is not a data type. If you mean integer, it will round the result and numeric wont remove the zeros in the end

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
  select cast(1234.20 as float   ) //1234.2
  select cast(01.00 as float ) //1  
  select cast(17.5 as float  ) //17.5   
  select cast(00.01 as float  ) //0.01  
  select cast(00.10 as float  ) //0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always get the values with php and `trim()` the zero's and commas out
then update your sql

that is if for some reason you cannot or dont want to change your sql's data types

Comment: What if PHP is not used in this project .. ?

Comment: right, but if this is a one-time edit he could use php to get over with it :)  just proposing alternatives